# a,svg,Page Builder от SiteOrigin WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, webview

Есть такой плагин как Page Builder от SiteOrigin. Хочу сделать такие же окошка [анимации](https://atom-media.ru/services/). Пишу код через билдер

```
    <a href="/kompleksnaya-strategiya/">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/line-1.svg" class="mainpage__service__svg" />
        <div class="mainpage__service__caption">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.svg" class="img-responsive mainpage__service__img" />
        <div class="mainpage__service__title">КОМПЛЕКСНАЯ<br>PERFORMANCE<br>СТРАТЕГИЯ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainpage__service__descr">
    Это комплексная стратегия продвижения в digital-среде, целью которой 
является достижение конкретных и измеримых результатов.
</div>
    </a>
```

Нажимаю сохранить и после этого блдер немного сам изменил сам код

```
    <a href="/kompleksnaya-strategiya/">
    <img class="mainpage__service__svg" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/line-1.svg" /></a>
    <div class="mainpage__service__caption">
<img class="img-responsive mainpage__service__img" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.svg" />
    <div class="mainpage__service__title">
КОМПЛЕКСНАЯ
    PERFORMANCE
    СТРАТЕГИЯ</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainpage__service__descr">
Это комплексная стратегия продвижения в digital-среде,
 целью которой является достижение конкретных и измеримых результатов.
</div>
```

И анимация не работает и текст плывет....[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
СSS стль вот(сами изображение svg)

```
.mainpage__service{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 80px 0;
    height: 280px;
    position: relative;
}
    .mainpage__service__svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mainpage__service__svg:hover {
    fill: #f4783e;
    /* цвет обводки */
    stroke: white;
    /* имя анимации (keyframes) */
    animation-name: draw_symbol;
    /* длительность анимации */
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
    .mainpage__service__svg {
        display: none;
    }
}
.mainpage__service__svg line {
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke: #F3773D;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-out;
}
.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.top,
.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.bottom {
    stroke-dasharray: 390;
}

.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.left,
.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.right {
    stroke-dasharray: 280;
}

.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.top{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-390px);
    transform: translateX(-390px);
}

.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(390px);
    transform: translateX(390px);
}

.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.left {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-280px);
    transform: translateY(-280px);
}

.mainpage__service .mainpage__service__svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(280px);
    transform: translateY(280px);
}


.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line {
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line {
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.top,
.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.left,
.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.mainpage__service__caption{
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.mainpage__service__img,
.mainpage__service__title{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainpage__service__img{
    fill: #18242c;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 122px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    -webkit-transition: fill .9s;
    -o-transition: fill .9s;
    transition: fill .9s;
}

.mainpage__service:hover .mainpage__service__img{
    fill: #F3773D;
}

.mainpage__service__img .st1{
    fill:#1e94d2
}
.mainpage__service__title{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: #18242c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px;
}
.mainpage__service__descr{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: rgba(24, 36, 44, 0.78);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 280px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: У вас в вёрстке ошибка, вот он и закрывает блоки, там где ему хочется.  Добавьте вконце перед тегом `</a>` закрывающий тег `</div>'

Comment: Никаких результатов оно не дало

Comment: Поправьте свой `html` в вопросе, чтобы было видно, где и что у вас должно лежать, тогда будет понятно, что и куда вы написали неверно.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по-другому, создал доп файл в формате .php вставил туда весь код, подключал через команду include(); и плагин PHP Code Widget, сделал отлично!